# Python - Wrap text in list

Tags: python, string, list, recursion

I am trying to write a function which takes some text and a list, and then if the last element in the list is small enough so that it can append text to that last element and still have less than 10 chars, then do it. Otherwise, append it to the list separately. The problem I'm having is that if text is for example 25 char long.

For example,

```
l = ["12345678", "123456789"]

>>> a("a", l)
["12345678", "123456789a"]

>>> a("123456789123456789123", l)
["12345678", "1234567891", "2345678912", "3456789123"]
```

This is what I have so far

```
def a(st, lst):
    last = 10 - len(lst[-1])

    if last < len(st):
        lst[-1] += st[:last]
        lst.append(st[last:])
    else:
        lst[-1] += st
```

Comment: Well if you have already *partially* working code, it is a good idea to share that. Since than we can point out what is wrong with it, and help you fix it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `st` (in your given function) **can be arbitrary long** and thus you have to **add an arbitrary amount of elements**. Now in case something is arbitrary, that usually **calls for a loop** (`for` or `while`).

The algorithm itself consists out of two phases: in the fist phase we check how much space is left in the last element of `lst`. We fill up that element with (a part of) `st`. You can do this with:

```
left = 10-len(lst[-1])
lst[-1] += st[:left]
```

Note that you do not need an `if` here: in case there is no space left, it will add no characters, and furthermore if there are too few characters in `st` the slicing will simply return a substring.

Now we only need to add the remaining characters in chunks of 10 to `lst`. We can do this by writing a `for` loop that starts at `left` (since we can omit the first `left` characters) and makes jumps of 10 positions until it hits the end of the `st`ring:

```
for i in range(left,len(st),10):
    # ... do something
    pass
```

It is quite clear what we have to do: add slices `st[i:i+10]` to the `lst`. So we turn the `for` loop into:

```
for i in range(left,len(st),10):
    lst.append(st[i:i+10])
```

finally we only have to return the `lst`. Putting it all together we got:

```
def a(st, lst):
    # phase 1
    left = 10-len(lst[-1])
    lst[-1] += st[:left]

    #phase 2
    for i in range(left,len(st),10):
        lst.append(st[i:i+10])

    return lst
```

Note that this solution **operates on the given list**. In case you want to make a copy, you can add one line:

```
def a(st, lst):
    # make copy
    lst = list(lst)

    # phase 1
    left = 10-len(lst[-1])
    lst[-1] += st[:left]

    #phase 2
    for i in range(left,len(st),10):
        lst.append(st[i:i+10])

    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to split with 10 characters! That would make the job simpler!

```
import re
l = ["12345678", "123456789"]
def a(add_str,l):
    add_str= l[-1]+add_Str
    print str

    return l[:-1] + re.findall('.{10}', add_str)+filter(None, re.split(r'.{10}', add_str))

print a("12345987659878", l)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What is the `filter` supposed to do? Are you sure you add the tailing characters (the remaining that do not sum up to 10 characters) at the end?

Comment: Exactly! That is why the second reflex is for.

Comment: Basically, filter(None, re.split(pattern,str))  gives all elements that doesn't match the reflex. Hope that answers your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following commented code:

```
def wrap(s, l):
    # How many characters to add to last element
    r = 10 - len(l[-1]) if l else 0

    # Augment last string
    if r > 0:
        l[-1] += s[:r]

    # Add remaining chunks of length 10
    for i in range(r, len(s), 10):
        l.append(s[i:i + 10])

    return l

l = ["12345678", "123456789"]

print(wrap("a", l))
print(wrap("123456789123456789123", l))
```

Result:

```
['12345678', '123456789a']
['12345678', '123456789a', '1234567891', '2345678912', '3']
```